# C++ Error 1 error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'records'

Tags: c++

TicTacToe.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Header.h"

class TicTacToe
{
    vector<char>tictac_array;
    Records records;
public:
    TicTacToe();

    ~TicTacToe();

    void push_tictac_array();

    int wincheck();

    void board(string player1, string player2);

    void start();

    void mainmenu();
};
```

Header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Records.h"
#include "TicTacToe.h"

using namespace std;
```

Records.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Header.h"

class Records
{
protected:
    vector<Records*> rec;
    string player;
    int wins;
    int games;
    int draws;
public:
    Records();
    Records(string player, int wins, int games, int draws);

    ~Records();

    void setName(string player);

    void setWins(int wins);

    void setGames(int games);

    void setDraws(int draws);

    string getName();

    int getWins();

    int getGames();

    int getDraws();

    void addRec(string player, int wins, int games, int draws);

    void sortStats();

    void outRec();

    void saveTo();

    void readFrom();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

const int NotUsed = system("color F0");


void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    TicTacToe tictac;
    tictac.records.readFrom();
    tictac.mainmenu();
}
```

Before the breakdown on the files and everything worked perfectly. Only after spread all classes file, began issuing this error, what could be the problem?
Added Records.h header file

Comment: I suspect a circular #include path, e.g. `Records.h` including `TicTacToe.h` via some route.

Comment: As a side note, it's never a good idea to put a `using namespace` declaration in a header file, as anything which includes that header will get that. I realise that is probably the behaviour you want at the moment, put it's much safer to put that declaration in your `.cpp` files or, better yet, fully qualify your references.

Comment: So.. `Header.h` includes `Records.h` which includes `Header.h`. Hmmmm....

Comment: Ok can you stop doing that please? Stop including `TicTacToe.h` and `Records.h` from `Header.h` and just include them in your `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to guard the `Header.h` file. Just put `#pragma once` at the top as you have done for `Records.h`

Answer (score 4):

How many confunsion.

**First of all**:

> - never use useless include in header files.
> - never use namespace in header files.

In **TicTacToe.h** you include **"Header.h"** that includes **"TicTacToe.h"** itself: recursion.

**Second**:

> "#pragma once" is not standard, so I recommend to use instance:

```
#ifndef RECORDS_H_
#define RECORDS_H_

class Records {
}

#endif
```

If you really want to use ["#pragma once"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), learn to use it before: it should be the first instruction, at least before all "inclues", generally.

**Third**:

- use keyword 'private' even tough it is implicit;
- get method should be const;
- pass parameters by references, you avoid useless copy.

TicTacToe.h

```
#ifndef TICTACTOE_H_
#define TICTACTOE_H_

#include <vector>

#include "Records.h"

class TicTacToe {
private:
    std::vector<char> tictac_array;
    Records records;
public:
    TicTacToe();
    ~TicTacToe();
    void push_tictac_array();
    int wincheck();
    void board(const std::string& player1, const std::string& player2);
    void start();
    void mainmenu();
};

#endif
```

Records.h

```
#ifndef RECORDS_H_
#define RECORDS_H_

#include <vector>

class Records {
protected:
    std::vector<Records*> rec;
    string player;
    int wins;
    int games;
    int draws;
public:
    Record();
    Record(const std::string& player, const int& wins, const int& games,const int& draws);
    ~Record();
    void setName(const std::string& player);
    void setWins(const int& wins);
    void setGames(const int& games);
    void setDraws(const int& draws);
    string getName() const;
    int getWins() const;
    int getGames() const;
    int getDraws() const;
    void addRec(const std::string& player, const int& wins, const int& games,const int& draws);
    void sortStats();
    void outRec();
    void saveTo();
    void readFrom();
};

#endif
```

Main:

```
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "TicTacToe.h"

using namespace std;

const int NotUsed = system("color F0");

void main() {
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    TicTacToe tictac;
    tictac.records.readFrom();
    tictac.mainmenu();
}
```

**Fourth:**

Records class is totally wrong: it has a std::vector of Records*, that make it recursive.
You should have instance:

Record.h

```
class Record {
    protected:
        string player;
        int wins;
        int games;
        int draws;
    public:
        Records();
        Records(const std::string& player, const int& wins, const int& games,const int& draws);
        ~Records();
        void setName(const std::string& player);
        void setWins(const int& wins);
        void setGames(const int& games);
        void setDraws(const int& draws);
        string getName() const;
        int getWins() const;
        int getGames() const;
        int getDraws() const;
        void addRec(const std::string& player, const int& wins, const int& games,const int& draws);
        void sortStats();
        void outRec();
        void saveTo();
        void readFrom();
    };
```

Records.h

```
class Records : public std::vector<Record*> {
}
```

This make more sense, for me at least.

Comment: `#pragma once` might not be _de jure_ standard, but it is _de facto_; support is very wide for it and it results in fewer errors due to copy-pasting and not altering the `#define`.

Comment: Okay, so your option is to either use a superior method which is supported by near any compiler you will use, or to use an inferior method in order to support those few which don't. I know which I would go for, particularly for a Tic-Tac-Toe game.

Comment: The only addition I can make to this is to avoid including system headers *before* custom headers when *both* are included in the same source file. Doing so can introduce *implicit* dependency that can be a biach to track down in large projects. Ex:, suppose `Records.h` did *not* properly include `<vector>`, but needed it for some member. Including `"Records.h"` stand-alone would fail, but including `TicTacToe.h` would succeed. Two schools of thought on this, but that's where I reside on it.

Comment: Well, and I'd also `#include <clocale>` and `#include <cstdlib>` in `main.cpp`, as both are needed for proper including of the declarations of `std::setlocale` and `std::system`